# Should I replace the entire deck structure?

Tags: wood, deck

The floorboards of my pressure-treated deck are quite old, and need to be replaced. The frame supporting it is mostly sound. Rather than replacing the entire structure, I'm considering keeping the underlying frame, repairing the joists and posts as necessary. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Wood is either good or bad, usually no in between.  Replace the bad.  Keep the good(good being no damage).  Being old, design regulations might have changed, what was okay before might not be now.

Comment: What may have been acceptable in the past may no longer be acceptable for _new_ construction, however, it may be "grandfathered" in when it comes to a simple refresh of the decking. Changes to the structure (replacing a joist or post that may be rotten) _could_ trigger an inspection as "new" work. Best check with your local AHJ to be sure. Also, the changes in code are to improve safety, not just annoy homeowners and increase costs, so it might be good to analyze the deck to see if upgrades can/should be made, even if not _required_.

Comment: You're definitely going to want to check with your local building authority and see what the requirements are.  If you touch it it's possible you'll need to bring the entire thing up to code which may be impossible.  Be sure you understand what can and cannot be done code-wise before you do anything with it.